# Is oAuth 2.0 the default login method in Facebook C# SDK?

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I was just wondering. I'm using FB C# SDK for my facebook applications.

Do I need to change anything to make sure everything keeps working after October 1st?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

oauth 2 was default starting from the first beta release of v5. so if you are using v5 you already are using oauth 2.0

But if you are using FB JS SDK for login make sure to set oaut:true and also update the Facebook C# SDK to minimum of v5.2 (no need for server side code changes.)

Comment: Very nice to have the record set straight on this. Thanks for answering Prabir.